# Ubuntu 15.04 grub doesn't load windows 8(shows a red screen with white stripes)

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8, 15.04

I recently bought a NEW dell inspiron 3543(i5 5th gen) laptop.
(I have used ubuntu before as duel boot with my older machines but didn't get this.)

I installed windows 8 and then ubuntu 15.04 to use my laptop as a dual boot machine.
Ubuntu worked fine but when I tried to load windows 8 it showed red screen with white stripes.
I waited a while and then windows loaded...
For a week I waited till that red screen disappear and then used windows.

Today I installed some drivers in windows os and it required a restart.
But on that time the red screen appears and never load windows.
I waited a long time with patience.
But I can't load windows.

*And the worst thing is I can't even access my hard disc(ubuntu says can't mount)
though I had turned off fast boot feature in windows long time before.

Any help will be  APPRECIATED
Additional info:- I have a NVidia graphic card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps it's not properly initializing the chipset or video card, or there is some issue with ACPI..If you can enter your BIOS Try to boot your windows Installation Disc....The Problem is due to ***Corrupted Drivers***.So it is better to reinstall Windows..

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: If Windows loads eventually, that means that the user can see things on the screen indicating that Windows has properly loaded, which means the graphics are working, which means there's no problem with graphics drivers.

Comment: ok then what is the problem you think & if there any solution that can resolve driver erors..(except reinstalling windows or system restore) as he mentioned that (ubuntu says can't mount)